# My firestore function is not responding to my vue components hook function "beforeRouteEnter"

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-router

> this is what's in my firestore file

```
import { db } from "./firebase"
import { collection, doc,onSnapshot,query} from "firebase/firestore"
import { ref, onUnmounted} from "vue"

export const uesQueryProject = async()=>{
const events =ref([])
const q = query(
  collection(db , "events")
)
const unsub = onSnapshot(q,(snapshot)=>{
  events.value=snapshot.docs.map(
    doc=>({
      id:doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    })
  )
})
onUnmounted(unsub)
return events
}
```

> This is what my vue components try to call from the life cycle hook

```
  beforeRouteEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {

uesQueryProject()
  .then(response => {
    next(comp => {
       console.log(response.data)
            if(response.data){
            console.log('yas')
            comp.events = response.data

            }
    
      })
  })
  .catch(() => {
    next({ name: 'NetworkError' })
  })
```

},

> so the (response.data) is empty i don't know why,i try to consol log (doc) in side the "useQueryProject" function and it works but in side the vue component function there is no responde

Comment: uesQueryProject doesn't return a promise. It's not suitable to be used here. Don't write it with Vue reactivity, just stick to promise control flow. Also beforeRouteEnter can initially run before an app is mounted, it's incorrect to rely on component lifecycle there

Comment: @Estus Flask can you help me with that

Comment: It's specific to firebase API, which I don't use now. Basically you need to just query it once and return a promise from a function. Not subscribe to subsequent updates.